# Physical reflections of prime-number distribution

Tags: prime-numbers, mathematical-physics

Not a purely mathematical question:

I have read somewhere that [Atomic Orbital](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_orbital) is closely related to the distribution of prime numbers, but I am unable to find any reference to that.

Can someone please explain this relation (if it even exists)?

Also, what other physical reflections of prime-number distribution are known?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a site devoted to such: [surprising connections between number theory and physics](http://empslocal.ex.ac.uk/people/staff/mrwatkin//zeta/surprising.htm)

Comment: No problem. Enjoy.

Comment: It seems I have to add, that to my knowledge prime numbers are no central concept in physics right now. However, as physics uses mathematics heavily, even primes and related mathematics shows up and that link features such connections. This is amazing, there might have been no such thing, but one should not overrate these results.